# ionic cordova app keeps pushing the screen up on input focus

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

my app keeps jumping up whenevever I try to fill any input.
This seems to happen in any input on my application, when the keyboard shows up, the screen is pushed up and the whole screen is moved up.

How to correct this?
 I also noticed that inputs on the top of screen don't cause any harm
but if it's an input in the middle or below it causes the screen to go up

I already have, on my config.xml file the following:

```
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
        <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
        <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
        <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

my inputs are for passwords and codes and look like this:

```
 <div class="loginForm">
    <input ng-disabled="authenticate" name="password" id="login_password" type="text" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="" required minlength="8" maxlength="8" ng-maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" ng-model="login.Password" class="textInput" style="-webkit-text-security: disc; text-security: disc;">
```

the css for this input is only:

```
.loginBox .loginForm {width: 100%;display: flex;flex-direction: column;}
.textInput {font-size: 18px;}
.loginForm {position: relative;}
```

Also when debugging on browser, I can the values of this particular line are changing:

my ionic

```
<ion-content class="loginBg" scroll="true" padding="true" has-header="false" has-bouncing="false">
```